# Add foreign key to all tables with same column name

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Is there way to alter all tables expect table "users" and add foreign key and CASCADE UPDATE on data upate if column with name "user_id" is in table? I can do it manually but is there easier way to do it?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

you can execute query "show tables" and foreach execute query "describe TABLE_NAME" and alter tables if it is needed